# Объединить 3 макроса в 1

Tags: excel, vba

Есть 3 подобных макроса, работают как ВПР, хочу объединить их в один, чтобы в случае сдвигов данных менять пришлось бы только в одном месте (Const lRwStart As Long = 13 ' начало диапазона' и тому подобное)
был код:

```html
Sub updateEO()
Dim aData(), aShop(), aRes()
Dim sPath As String, dDate As Date, bFlag As Boolean
Dim i As Long, k As Long
Dim lClmn As Long
Const sFolder As String = "I:\..."
Const lRwStart As Long = 13 ' начало диапазона'
    With ActiveSheet
        i = 125 ' завершение диапазона'
        If i < 5 Then Exit Sub
        aShop = .Cells(lRwStart, 1).Resize(i - lRwStart + 1, 1).Value
    End With

    ReDim aRes(1 To UBound(aShop), 1 To 1)
    dDate = Date

    Do
        sPath = sFolder & "Экономический отчет (" & Format(dDate, "dd.mm.yyyy") & ").xls"
        If Dir(sPath, vbDirectory) <> "" Then bFlag = True: Exit Do  ' файл найден'
        dDate = dDate - 1 ' если не найден, уменьшаем дату для следующего имени файла'
    Loop Until dDate = Date - 5 ' просматриваем максимум 5 файлов (5 дат)'

    If bFlag = False Then MsgBox "Нет файла-донора", 64, "ОШИБКА": GoTo err_

    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .DisplayAlerts = False: End With

    With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sPath) ' открыть книгу'
        With Worksheets(Format(dDate, "dd.mm.yyyy")) ' если есть сомнения в наличии листа, нужна доп. проверка'
            i = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row - 1
            aData = .Range("B1:K" & i).Value
        End With

        .Close
    End With

    For k = 1 To UBound(aShop)
        For i = 1 To UBound(aData)
            If aShop(k, 1) = aData(i, 1) Then aRes(k, 1) = aData(i, 10) ' записываем найденное'
        Next i
    Next k

    With ActiveSheet
        lClmn = Application.Match("за день", Range("A12:ZZ12"), 0) ' строка в которой искать "за день"'
        .Cells(lRwStart, lClmn).Value = dDate ' дата  файла'
        .Cells(lRwStart, lClmn).Resize(UBound(aRes), 1).Value = aRes ' выгрузка на лист'
    End With
err_:
    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .DisplayAlerts = True: End With
End Sub
```

Часть из 2го макроса которую хочу добавить к первому:

```html
    With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sPath) ' открыть книгу'
        With Worksheets(Format(dDate, "dd.mm.yyyy")) ' если есть сомнения в наличии листа, нужна доп. проверка'
            i = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row - 1
            aData = .Range("B1:R" & i).Value
        End With

        .Close
    End With

    For k = 1 To UBound(aShop)
        For i = 1 To UBound(aData)
            If aShop(k, 1) = aData(i, 1) Then aRes(k, 1) = aData(i, 17) ' записываем найденное'
        Next i
    Next k

    With ActiveSheet
        lClmn = Application.Match("% мес", Range("A12:ZZ12"), 0) ' строка в которой искать "% мес"'
        .Cells(lRwStart, lClmn).Value = dDate ' дата  файла'
        .Cells(lRwStart, lClmn).Resize(UBound(aRes), 1).Value = aRes ' выгрузка на лист'
    End With
```

Работает, но не уверен, что так правильно делать, не будут ли переменные друг об друга путаться и тп? или может еще короче сделать можно

Comment: Опять этот код... Для чего у Вас три подобных макроса? Один с чем не справляется?

Comment: Что поделать, пытаюсь разобраться в не известном мне, дабы упростить жизнь и себе и своему отделу) 3 потому, что они для разных данных, тут это видно: lClmn = Application.Match("% мес". По сути одно и тоже для трех разных столбцов. И берет данные с разных листов донора

Comment: Ну так выносите разницу из хардкода в массив переменных или констант.

Comment: По Вашей исходной задаче данные нужно брать из одного листа, имя которого - наибольшая дата меньше сегодняшней. А как теперь, если обрабатывать несколько листов?

Comment: не совсем, в названии файла донора ближайшая дата к текущей (может быть и текущая), а листы называются: 1й - дата (такая же что в имени донора) 2й - "по филиалам". Вот я и сделал 3 макроса, для каждого листа свой